# Apply same styles on all headers tag within a div

Tags: html, css

I want apply some styles on all `(h1,h2,...,h6)` within a div with for example `.header` class in order to do that I write following css in my document.

```
.header h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

problem occurs when I want to use `(h1,h2,...,h6)` somewhere else outer of `div.header`.
Same styles applies on them too. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: try adding .header before each h1,h2,h3 like this? .header h1, .header h2, .header h3

Comment: ya it works thx for idea, but it's kinda code duplicate, I'm looking for a way to group these h1,...,h6 tags.

Comment: I think this is the shortest way to do this. I don't know a better way then this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're only restricting `h1` to your `.header` div.  Change to:

```
.header h1,
.header h2,
.header h3,
.header h4,
.header h5,
.header h6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent these duplications? reduce .header to only one and group h tags?

Comment: No, and don't think of it as duplication.  This is just how CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

When [CSS Nesting](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting) is ready you can get rid of the duplication in your final CSS.

With SCSS you can do the following to get rid of duplication in your code but it will be compiled into what is in the accepted answer.

```scss
.header {
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
  }
}
```